# Automatically mark autogenerated headers as TODO in Visual Studio/ReSharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, todo

I'm pretty sure that I have in the past set up Visual Studio 2012 and/or ReSharper so that when I tell ReSharper to insert a documentation header for an undocumented class or function or whatever, it includes "TODO" in the header.  But now I'm trying to make that happen on another machine, and I have not yet been able to find how to do it.  Does anyone know? This is in C#, in case that matters.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I've got it: Tools / Options / ReSharper / Options / Tools / Style Cop / Insert TODO into headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I've got it: Tools / Options / ReSharper / Options / Tools / Style Cop / Insert TODO into headers.